# How can node.js keep track of many requests made to the same endpoint?

Tags: node.js, express

Let say I have an endpoint that perform some background IO work before sending a response like this code below:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  someIOWork(() => {
      res.send('Some response');
  });
});
```

My understanding is that node will not block the main thread in this case. So while waiting for the IO work to finish, it will process any next incoming request, and once that background work is done, then it will send the response. What I have hard time understanding is how can node keep track of which response to send to which request? I hope my question was clear and thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript closures make it work. The callback to your `someIOWork()` has a reference to the `req` and `res` objects. They are tied to that one specific connection you are responding to. Other invocations or your route handler have different `req` and `res` objects representing separate connections.

There's a longer explanation of this specific situation where Node.js serves multiple requests while one call is performing IO at [100 new requests in Node.js while still serving the first one](https://bytearcher.com/articles/100-new-requests-while-still-serving-the-first-one/)